# Incorrect BME688 Gas reistance values

Tags: linux, driver, linux-device-driver, beagleboneblack, iio

We are using the already built driver for *BME680* sensor from the Linux kernel v5.10. But we need *BME688* so we compared the datasheet and got to know that T,P,H calculations and registers are same for both *BME680* and *BME688*. The only difference we noticed is Gas resistance registers and calculations. So according to the datasheet we modified those register values and calculations and tried integrating the sensor using **BeagleBone Black** board, we are getting T,P,H same but gas resistance is getting increased gradually but when we keep a alcohol near to it is sensing and decreasing the resistance and after again it's starts increasing gradually. I am adding below what are the changes made. So, it will be help full to me if your team can check and give me any suggestion to how to solve it.

```auto
// Registers I changed for Gas resistance
// BME680 to BME688

define BME680_REG_GAS_MSB      0x2A      to    0x2C
define BME680_REG_GAS_R_LSB    0x2B      to    0x2D
define BME680_GAS_STAB_BIT     BIT(4)    to    BIT(5)
define BME680_RUN_GAS_MASK     BIT(4)    to    BIT(5)
```

**Actual code for BME680**

```c
static u32 bme680_compensate_gas(struct bme680_data *data, u16 gas_res_adc, u8 gas_range)
{
    struct bme680_calib *calib = &data->bme680;
    s64 var1;
    u64 var2;
    s64 var3;
    u32 calc_gas_res;

    /* Look up table for the possible gas range values */

    const u32 lookupTable[16] = {2147483647u, 2147483647u,
    2147483647u, 2147483647u, 2147483647u,
    2126008810u, 2147483647u, 2130303777u,
    2147483647u, 2147483647u, 2143188679u,
    2136746228u, 2147483647u, 2126008810u,
    2147483647u, 2147483647u};

    var1 = ((1340 + (5 * (s64) calib->range_sw_err)) * ((s64) lookupTable[gas_range])) >> 16;
    var2 = ((gas_res_adc << 15) - 16777216) + var1;
    var3 = ((125000 << (15 - gas_range)) * var1) >> 9;
    var3 += (var2 >> 1);
    calc_gas_res = div64_s64(var3, (s64) var2);

    return calc_gas_res;
}
```

**Calculations what I made according to BME688 from the datasheet**

```c
static u32 bme680_compensate_gas(struct bme680_data *data, u16 gas_res_adc, u8 gas_range)
{
    struct bme680_calib *calib = &data->bme680;
    u32 var1;
    u32 var2;
    u32 calc_gas_res;

    var1 = U32_C(262144) >> gas_range;
    var2 = gas_res_adc - S32_C(512);
    var2 *= S32_C(3);
    var2 = S32_C(4096) + var2;
    calc_gas_res = ((U32_C(10000) * var1) / var2) * 100;

    return calc_gas_res;
}
```

**BME680 Readings**

```auto
Humidity: 59.07%rH
Temp: 27.70DegC
Pressure: 907.9hpa
Resistance: 67998ohms

Humidity: 58.98%rH
Temp: 27.70DegC
Pressure: 907.9hpa
Resistance: 69906ohms
```

**BME688 Readings**

```auto
Humidity: 55.95%rH
Temp: 28.18DegC
Pressure: 907.1hpa
Resistance: 15100ohms

Humidity: 55.94%rH
Temp: 28.19DegC
Pressure: 907.1hpa
Resistance: 15500ohms
```

BME688 Gas resistance values are getting from 5600 slowly increasing after sometime it reached some level.